# How to get the Path of a given controller route/action without specifying the parameters in twig Template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I use this line to get the path of a controller named "finddealer"

In this way:

```
{{ path('finddealer', { 'field': null, 'value': null }) }}
```

Is there a way to omit the parameters from the second argument even though they are required ? or there is something different than path that I can use?

I would like to get the path of a given controller route/action without the parameters.

Comment: Without the parameters, the path cannot be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the default option on your route annotation. If you use the default option then you don't need to define it when you call your function on the Twig

```
class YourController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/exsample/{field}/{value}", name="finddealer", defaults={"field": null, "value": null})
     */
    public function finddealer(int $field, string $value)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```